# Program that ask user for input and tries matching with regex, until user just presses enter

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, while-loop, user-input

What I need to do is match user input with a regular expression and have a function return True or False based on a matching/not matching input. If it matches, a positive response will be printed, and vice versa. The def is not supposed to print anything in itself. This will loop until a user only inputs enter, resulting in the program just exiting. As of now, when I press enter, the program keep trying to match the input to the pattern. So it is there that I'm completely stuck.

I've been trying things like having different statements for the `except` block, having another pattern with only a newline character and specifying it on the `except` block, but as I'm super new to programming I'm having a hard time knowing what to look for to solve this. I've searched for things like: "exiting while loop when input not match regex", "exit when user input enter" etc. to no avail. I just can't wrap my head around how I should structure this to be able to achieve a program working as intended. I believe my issue is within the `while` loop

So here is my code so far. You can ignore the regex pattern as it is only a placeholder for now. The `except` block is just empty now as I am out of ideas and really frustrated. I hope I'm not vague or incoherent in my description of the program and my problem, if so I'll update my post with more information.

```
valid_name = re.compile(r"[A-Z][a-z]")

def name(user_in):
    if valid_name.match(user_in.strip()):
        return True
    else:
        return False

while True:
    user_in = input("Enter a name (use uppercase for first letter): ")
    try:
        if name(user_in) == True:
            print("Name '", user_in.strip(), "' is valid!", sep="")
        else:
            print("Name '", user_in.strip(), "' is invalid!", sep="")
    except:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. Here is my update to the `while` loop:

```
while True:
    user_in = input("Enter a name (use uppercase for first letter): ")
    if not user_in:
        break
    else:
        stripped = user_in.strip()
        if name(user_in(stripped) == True:
            print("Name '", stripped, "' is valid!", sep="")
        else:
            print("Name '", stripped, "' is invalid!", sep="")
```

I also made a new variable, stripping the input, instead of having the strip-function in the function. Not sure what best practice is here.